# Where is pip's cache in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Where is pip's cache when using a virtual environment? Is it the default cache? If so, won't those downloaded packages/wheels remain if you delete the virtual environment?

Comment: It uses the default cache, on posixlikes this is usually `~/.cache/pip` on windows it's usually `%LOCALAPPDATA%/pip/cache`

Comment: On macOS with Python 3.11, it is `~/Library/Caches/pip`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pip uses the default cache indeed, whether you're working inside a virtualenv or not. This indeed means that after removing your virtualenv, any pip cache related to it is not removed.

Mind that the installed packages themselves are deleted, just not the download cache.

Why would that be a problem? I think this is expected behaviour, since you gain an advantage when installing the same package in another virtualenv later on.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check this? Also what do you mean the installed packages are deleted but the download cache remains? For instance, I see when I `pip install numpy` that a numpy zip file is downloaded but I have no idea where to. It's not in the default cache location. And I've looked but haven't found an explanation for this.

Comment: Just create a new virtualenv, enable it, pip install a package in it and then check your default cache (in my case I could see many new files added to `~/.cache/pip/`) which were still there after removing the virtualenv.

On *nix you can easily investigate this with tools like `find` or even a couple of `ls -rt`s. :-)

Comment: It's a problem when one virtualenv uses python rev A and another virtualenv uses python rev B and wheel caches it's built crap in the same spot but the built wheel binaries have hard-coded references to incorrect python revs in them...

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution was simple:
I had to use the function: --no-cache-dir

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score -2):

According to documentation [pip caching](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching)

> The default location for the cache directory depends on the Operating
>   System

Comment: Does this account for using a virtualenv? Please note.