# In virtualenv, where is the default directory of python pip install's .whl cache files? both for win7 and ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, caching, pip, virtualenv

I'm using `virtualenv` on win7. 
`> python -m pip install [packagename]`.
My question is where is the default cache directory of `pip` in `virtualenv`? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is pip's cache in a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349624/where-is-pips-cache-in-a-virtualenv)

Answer (score 1):

Wheel cache is venv-independent. It's always `%LOCALAPPDATA%\pip\Cache` so that `pip` can install the same cached wheels in multiple venvs.

Comment: thank u. But only few `.whl` files have been included in the 
 `%LOCALAPPDATA%\pip\Cache\wheel\ ` place, I've got much more than that packages installed. Any clue?

Comment: Seems to be true for me, too: in subdirectory `http` I have 2036 files and dirs, in `wheel` only 841. Perhaps `pip` clears the wheel cache sometimes but not download cache.