# How to install python packages in a virtual environment without downloading them again?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtual-environment

It's a great hassle when installing some packages in a VE and conda or pip downloads them again even when I already have it in my base environment. Since I have limited internet bandwidth and I'm assuming I'll work with many different VE's, it will take a lot of time to download basic packages such as OpenCV/Tensorflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, pip [caches](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching) anything it downloads, and will used the cached version whenever possible. This cache is [shared between your base environment and all virtual environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349624/where-is-pips-cache-in-a-virtualenv/46349941). So unless you pass the `--no-cache-dir` option, pip downloading a package means it has not previously downloaded a compatible version of that package. If you already have that package installed in your base environment or another virtual environment and it downloads it anyway, this probably means one or more of the following is true:

- You installed your existing version with a method other than pip.
- There is a newer version available, and you didn't specify, for example, `pip install pandas=1.1.5` (if that's the version you already have elsewhere). Pip will install the newest compatible version for your environment, unless you tell it otherwise.
- The VE you're installing to is a different Python version (e.g. created with [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)), and needs a different build.

I'm less familiar with the specifics of conda, and I can't seem to find anything in its online docs that focuses on the default caching behavior. However, a how-to for [modifying the cache location](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/shared-pkg-cache/) seems to assume that the default behavior is similar to how pip works. Perhaps someone else with more Anaconda experience can chime in as well.

So except for the caveats above, as long as you're installing a package with the same method you did last time, you shouldn't have to download anything.

If you want to simplify the process of installing all the same packages (that were installed via pip) in a new VE that you already have in another environment, pip can automate that too. Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the first environment, and copy the resulting file to your newly created VE. There, run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and pip will install all the packages that were installed (via pip) in the first environment. (Note that `pip freeze` records version numbers as well, so this won't install newer versions that may be available -- whether this is a good or bad thing depends on your needs.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one last question, in the conda cache folder configuration, I'm assuming I give a directory of my choice right? But then I won't be able to directly install the packages that come bundled with conda and would have to install them at least once on my own?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have misread that Anaconda page I linked. (I've edited my answer.) Best as I can tell, it seems that `conda install` does basically the same thing `pip install` does, inasmuch as it caches everything it downloads, and reuses from the cache when possible. I'm not 100% positive it's shared between environments, but it certainly seems to be what is implied.